# Run-time error '3061'

Tags: vba, ms-access

Problem updating date and time of the user's log off from database

In Login Form on Enter button have next code:

```
Dim db1 As DAO.Database
Dim KorIme As String 
Dim rst1 As DAO.Recordset
Set db1 = CurrentDb()
Set rst1 = db1.OpenRecordset("tblLogPristupa", dbOpenDynaset)
rst1.AddNew
rst1!KorIme = Me.txtKorisnickoIme.Value
rst1!IDKorisnika = Me.txtKorisnickoIme.Column(5)
rst1!DatumPristupa = Date
rst1!VrijemePristupa = Time()
rst1.Update
rst1.Close
```

In Form `frmOsnovna` on `LogOff` Button have next code:

```
Dim strSQL As String

Dim db As DAO.Database

Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb()

strSQL = "SELECT tblLogPristupa.IdPristupa, tblLogPristupa.KorIme, tblLogPristupa.DatumOdjave, tblLogPristupa.VrijemeOdjave FROM tblLogPristupa WHERE((tblLogPristupa.IdPristupa)=(Select Max(IdPristupa) FROM tblLogPristupa WHERE tblLogPristupa.KorIme = Me.KorisnikID));"

Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)' HERE IS ERROR 3061

rst.Edit

rst!DatumOdjave = Date

rst!VrijemeOdjave = Time()

rst.Update

rst.Close
```

Databases is multi-user. I need write in `tblLogPristupa`, date and time logoff for each user.

Currently this code not working good. Please if anyone can correct this code.

Any second solutions is good. Thank you advanced.

Answer (score 0):

3061 means Too few parameters - which most often translates to referring to a non-existing field. To find out which field, you must know what the database looks like. If you recreate the query in Access query designer, you will find that you'll get better error messages there.

Comment: Too few parameters. Expected 1

Comment: Exactly. Now, you can start deconstructing your query until you find the culprit

Comment: Exactly, I've tried everything I knew before I contacted the help here on the forum.

Comment: In Query this work but in VBA not working... I'm confused

Comment: If you get that error message it means that there is some information that Access needs to understand the query. After a more careful look at your SQL, I think the most likely candidate is the = Me.KorisnikID part. This implies that you have a form with a user id, which is available when you run the code with the form open. When the form isn't open, that field isn't available, which gives the error. If you replace Me.KorisnikID with a user id, within apostrophes, you'll hopefully get a better result. If so - the you'll have to think how to make that work without hardcoding.

Comment: just copy the SQL string from Query and put it into your code after the _strSQL =_ line.

Comment: IF click on X to close form then work fine but if click to next button Private Sub cmdIzlazO_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_cmdIzlazO_Click
    Do While Forms.Count > 0
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Forms(0).Name
    Loop
    DoCmd.Quit
    
Exit_cmdIzlazO_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_cmdIzlazO_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_cmdIzlazO_Click
    
End
End Sub
I got next error: "There is an invalid use of the . (dot) or ! operator or invalid parentheses". I'm try change ! with . but nothing

Comment: Thank you guys for help!
I'm much experiment with all combination and finally got the solution.

This is:

WHERE [tblLogPristupa].[KorIme] = " & "'" & Me.KorisnikID & "'" & "));"

Working nice... Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

The control's value is in the query's SQL. This needs to be attached to the string.

Change:

```
"...WHERE tblLogPristupa.KorIme = Me.KorisnikID));"
```

To:

```
"...WHERE tblLogPristupa.KorIme = " & Me!KorisnikID & "));"
```